# Does this second-order system of nonhomogeneous ODE have bounded solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, boundary-value-problem

The equations of motion for a bead on a smooth, freely rotating rod with unit length are

$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
0&= \omega_0^2\sin\theta - x\dot{\theta}^2+\ddot{x}\\
0&=3\omega_0^2\cos\theta (1+2\mu x)+ 12\mu x \dot{x}\dot{\theta}+2\ddot{\theta}(1+3\mu x^2)
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

Is it possible to tell without solving the equations what parameters $\{\omega_0,\mu\}$ and initial conditions $\{x(0), \dot{x}(0),\theta(0),\dot{\theta}(0)\}$ would lead to a bounded $x(t)?$

I tried to solve the equations numerically. With some $\{\omega_0,\mu\}$, $x(t)$ would oscillate for a while. But it would always end up diverging with a long enough time scale.

Linear divergence at $\omega_0=10^{-3},\mu=10,\theta'(0)=-2,x(0)=x'(0)=\theta(0)=0$

[image]

Technically the solution is meaningless for $x(t)>1$ since the length of the rod is $1$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, and if it's not too much hassle, what sort of behavior do you see with $\theta(0) = 0$ and $x(0) = -1/(2\mu)$?

Comment: A bit on the heuristic side, but maybe worth noting, the $\ddot{x} - \dot{\theta}^2x$ term in the first equation hints at exponential growth in $x$.

Comment: @Aruralreader asymptotically it converges to $x(t)=-\omega_0 t^2/2$